# pathlib's Path("NUL:").resolve() throws an error on windows. Is this a bug?

Tags: python, windows, pathlib, dev-null

I'm looking for the equivalent windows functionality to the posix `/dev/null` file, and I discovered `NUL:`

This snippet works on a windows OS, proving that it is indeed a writable file: `Path('NUL:').write_text('abcd')`

However, `Path('NUL:').resolve()` Throws an exception `OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect: 'NUL:'`

Is this a bug I should report or is this the expected behaviour? I.E. I should wrap the call to `resolve()` in a `try...except`?

If I catch all `OSError` types, how can I determine if it's a legitimate error or not?

E.G. Full console output:

```
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('NUL:')
WindowsPath('NUL:')
>>> Path('NUL:').write_text('abcd')
4
>>> Path('NUL:').resolve()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\pathlib.py", line 1134, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\pathlib.py", line 192, in resolve
    s = self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect: 'NUL:'
```

Comment: I think you should also raise the same question [here](https://bugs.python.org/)

Comment: This might be something you already know, but for reference, you can use `os.devnull`: `pathlib.Path(os.devnull)`. On my Windows, `os.devnull` evaluates to `'nul'`.